# Cant set image to backBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i have `UITableView` based application, and i can't set `backBarButtonItem` properly.
Back button is button, which appears when i select any item, call second view with method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  When i try to set it like this:

```
UIButton *back1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [back1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, 45.0, 40.0)];
    [back1 addTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [back1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:back1];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
```

There is just back button with default style and somehow with title of my `TableView` controller window.

When i set it like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"]
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:nil 
                               action:nil];

 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

There is an image, but, it look like "inserted" in default back button, doesn't look nice at all.

Please help me.. i tried many ways to solve this, but, in many cases there is just default Back button with title "Products" (there is title which appears on top of navigation bar in my `UITableView`). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
   UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"];
   UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [backButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  backButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
 backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
 [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMeter) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
       initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create resizable images
UIImage *myButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourButton"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];


//Set the background image for *all* UIBackBarButtons
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:myButton forState:UIControlStateNormal 
    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thank you James but it still same problem(

Comment: Did it change the image at all?

Comment: Well, i wonder why it happen, but it does replace title for back button (from "Back" to "Products", "Products" is displayed on center of my top navigation bar)

Comment: If you want to set the back button title to your own you have to use this code in your viewDidLoad: /Set back button title
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle: @"Back"
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target: nil action: nil];
    
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: Im already have one.. a plus button in top left corner. Also with custom image.